# Variables in TFS Mappings on Visual Studio Online Team Builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have created a VSO build using the new Team build system which uses TFS as the Repository.  I would like to introduce a variable into the Mappings -> Map value but when I do I get this error:

```
TF10122: The path '$/YourProject/${Build}' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or do I need to just hard code my Map path?

Comment: I'd just say that you pretty clearly proved that you can't. Why do you want it to be a variable, anyway? Your application's path shouldn't vary from build to build. Also, for the record, variables are accessed as `$(Variable)`, not `${Variable}`

Comment: I'd like one place to specify the build name for any usage I have.  And I haven't proved anything other then I don't know if there is a way to escape things so that it works :)

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille, is your requirement to customize build number? You can't achieve that via setting mappings folder, check my reply below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mappings on the Repository page are used to specify source control folder which contains projects that need to be built in the build definition. You can set it via clicking the Ellipsis (...) button, however, you can't include variables in the mapping path.

Comment: But if you want to weigh in on that missing feature, there is an Idea on Uservoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14131002-allow-variables-in-repository-variables-and-trigg

Comment: This has now been resolved for VSTS and TFS2017, however you will still get this error if you use an underscore in your variable name. i.e. MyPath = Good, My_Path = Bad

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue, i'd like to set the branch being built in order to have a single build that I can link to a single release (in vso), since the vso release system does not have global environment definitions.

Anyway, this used to be possible but they [removed this capability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/08/01/vnext-build-using-a-variable-for-server-path-for-repository-is-not-supported/) without replacing it with something else, kinda annoying.

I worked around it by adding mappings to both my dev and main branch to different local folders and then using a variable to differentiate between them in *the actual build steps*. As long as you don't need to map a ton of branches this works, even though its a bit cumbersome.