# Using wildcards in TFS build definition source path

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to set Source Control Folder path in the build definition in TFS 2013 or TFS 2015 using wildcards?

Comment: Why do you need this, i.e. how is it supposed to work? For example, what should happen when multiple folders match? Should they all be checked-out by TFS, should all matching "project" files be built? (Having that said, I don't think it is possible).

Comment: Could you explain more clearly which place you want to use wildcards?

Comment: example. So the build definition source control folder would be like

Comment: Sorry did not know when it hit enter to go to the next line it would sent it. Here the rest of my example               $/DEV/projoctectname/Feature/name_1.1.0 I would like to do something like  $/DEV/projoctectname/Feature/name_* So I would not have to change the build definition when name_1.1.0 is merged into the main branch and we create a new feature branch like $/DEV/projoctectname/Feature/name_1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the source path is the project path which need to build. As Christian.K mentioned, it's impossible. TFS can't build a few projects at the same time.

If you want to using wildcards in the source control folder path on the Source Settings tab. It's also not support. This one specify the version-control folders that contain the files that your build process requires. You can specify the only folders that contain files that your build process requires to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible. This case discusses the same request as yours: [Variables in TFS Mappings on Visual Studio Online Team Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402043/variables-in-tfs-mappings-on-visual-studio-online-team-builds)