# TFS 2015 builds : Is it possible to use Variables in Repository mappings?

Tags: build, asp.net-core, tfs-2015

When creating a vNext build on TFS 2015 you can define variables, which are then used in build steps, and can also be used as environment variables in scripts the build runs.

The build I am working on runs scripts that pulls files from mapped locations, so it would be great if I could define a variable and use it in a mapping so that for example, if I update a reference in the project the build is building, I can simply update the variable with the new location and have the repository mappings and scripts all pull correctly from the new location without having to make the change in multiple places.

I have tried doing this by setting up the variable and mapping as follows,
[image] 
[image]
But this generates an error when you try to save the build complaining that there are two '$' characters in the mapping.  Is there way to do this or is this not currently possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible. Just as the error message mentioned: there are two '$' characters in the mapping. Which means your application's path shouldn't vary from build to build.

> Mappings on the Repository page are used to specify source control
>   folder which contains projects that need to be built in the build
>   definition. You can set it via clicking the Ellipsis (...) button,
>   however, you can't include variables in the mapping path.

There is a similar question: [Variables in TFS Mappings on Visual Studio Online Team Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402043/variables-in-tfs-mappings-on-visual-studio-online-team-builds)

Comment: You are correct on the function, but wrong on the assertion that the paths shouldn't change from build to build.  It is common to have more than one environment during development and the process for building these ideally, should be identical. By entering these separate subtrees/branches manually, this becomes a point of failure and also muddies the build environment up with duplicate entries that do the exact same thing. This is tantamount to entering duplicate data into a database for something like customer address and is a serious design flaw.

Answer (score 5):

This has been causing me havok for quite a while as well.

For starters, there is a uservoice request for this feature. You can add your votes and input here to get Microsoft to allow this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14131002-allow-variables-in-repository-variables-and-trigg

Second, we've developed a workaround that gets us most of the way there. It's not perfect, but it might be useful to you if you're comfortable with the tradeoffs or can work around the deficiencies.

Start by turning off the "Label Sources" option of the build and mapping the Server Path field to you base build. You'll want to add a custom variable to the Build Definition to tell the build instance what TFS location to pull from. For example, we have a base project and then multiple branches from the project, so our source is structured like this

```
$\Team Project\Project1
$\Team Project\Project1Branch1
$\Team Project\Project1Branch2
$\Team Project\Project1Branch3
```

and we create a variable named "Branch" that we can set to "Branch1", "Branch2", and so forth.

When we want to build the base project, we leave the Branch variable blank when launching the build. For branch builds, we set it to the name of the branch we want to build.

Then our build steps look like this

- Remap Workspace Folder to Branch Folder
- Get Files for Specified Branch - We have to do this manually after
  remapping our workspace
- Compile the Source in the Specified  Branch
- Publish Build Artifacts from the Specified Branch
- Label the Code of the Specified Branch Manually

The Remap task runs the command

```
tf workfold "$/Team Project/Project1$(Branch)" "$(build.sourcesDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)$(Branch)"
```

The Manual Get task runs the following command

```
get /recursive /noprompt "$/Team Project/Project1$(Branch)"
```

The build uses the Branch variable to point to the correct location of the solution file for the specified branch

```
$(build.sourcesDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)$(Branch)\SolutionFile.sln
```

The Publish Artifacts task uses the Branch variable in both the Contents field and the Path field
Example in Contents

```
**\$(Build.DefinitionName)$(Branch)\bin
```

The Label Code task uses the following command

```
tf label "$(build.buildNumber)" "$/Team Project/Project1$(Branch)" /recursive
```

The downside of this setup is that you don't capture Associated Changes and Work Items to your subsidiary branches as the Server Path field is always set to the main location. This may not be an issue if you always merge from your branches to your main location prior to launching a build meant to go to production. What you can do to compensate for this really depends on your use case.

With some tweaking, you could use this same format to specify full paths as well if you needed to.

Comment: You fixed the problem in an elegant way within the limitations of VSTS. However there are performance issues using this approach. We have quite many releases branches and having to check everything out before a build I think would be quite slow.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say, "having to check everything out before a build." Checking files shouldn't be necessary in this case (although our builds have a checkout operation, they're not necessary for this issue and I simply neglected to remove references to them and am not seeing them now).

Comment: After pondering your comment for a while, I think you are referring to the "Get" operations on each branch. If so, don't fret - the solution above only "Gets" the source from the Main location (the path in the Server Path field) and the specific branch specified by the "Branch" variable. So while it's true that it "Gets" one unnecessary branch unless it's specifically a Main build, it's only one - it doesn't "Get" each branch in the solution.