# TFS2015 vNext missing features

Tags: continuous-integration, tfs-2015

I have been working with TeamCity, Jenkins and Bamboo my last 8years. Latest 2years very involved in ContinuousIntegration factory setup and mainteinance on my team with very good results, giving me a lot of habits about how to deal with builds, artifacts and pipelines.

Now, i'm on a new company, new team, new CI, TFS2015, first time for me.

Just one month before I arrive to this new team they were on TFS2012, with XAMLs, so I took the migration to vNext builds.

At first look, I found on vNext builds the classic build definition, i mean adding steps as a single task to the build, instead of monolithic XAML file.

But with the time, i was trying to create more complex builds, like TeamCity build chains, but this is not possible, strike one...

Then, I was trying to deal with multiple branches, one continuous build for each branch (we are on TFSVC), create packages from each branch, and I found I was duplicating my builds just to change repository paths and a few details, so I moved builds to templates trying to reuse build definitions, introducing variables to generates paths(for repos and branches) and versions and expecting to change only in one place the build and having this changes reflected in all builds derived from templates... but that's was not the case... :

variables are not accepted everywhere, like in repo paths.

can't change templates after created them, just replace them, and builds created from templates are not affected after template is changed. 
strike two ?.....

I'm wondering if maybe I'm doing things wrong with TFS, maybe this is a different system and I can't do things like in other CIs.

Any advice in how to approach TFS to have a good, dynamic and reusable set of builds ??

Answer (score 0):

here isn’t the feature that the changes of a build definition or template affects other existing build definitions.

If the build steps of build definitions are the same for each branch, you just need a build definition and add filters for each branch (Triggers > Continuous integrations (CI), after that it will uses corresponding source to build for CI build, for example, develop branch changes > Trigger a build automatically with develop branch source.

On the other hand, you can change branch and source version when queue build manually or through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build).

[image]

If the build steps are different for each branch, you need to modify the definitions independently for detail requirements.

Comment: well, in my local TFS2015, with TFSVC, I dont see branch selection. I think it is only available when using Git.. right?

Comment: @user810917 The TFVC system has the branch feature，but you can't specify branch when queue build，you need to change source mapping in repository of build definition. You can map multiple items/branches in a build and just build the projects in a branch, but it will takes more time to download source to build agent. It seems that git system is better for you. The TFVC team project supports git repository too, you may consider add a new git repository to your team project.

Comment: Yes, I already though on Git, but it is big impact on Team, so I'm trying to get the best result from current scenario: TFVC. seems not good to me current TFS version (2015), lack of lots cool features we can find in other CIs...

Comment: @user810917 What about this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453360/tfs-2015-builds-is-it-possible-to-use-variables-in-repository-mappings/40313404#40313404